# creating a vector from a given URL in R(HW question)

Tags: r, computer-science

[image]

I was able to do the first part of this question as

```
print(read.table("http://oeis.org/A000796/b000796.txt"))
```

For the second part, I am not sure if I should plug in the numbers directly from the second column or if there is an easier way to do this I was thinking

```
A<-read.table("http://oeis.org/A000796/b000796.txt")
```

A1<-C(.....)with the numbers in the second column

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am a beginner in R so I am sorry if I am unclear in advance.

Comment: I have A1<-c(3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,5,8,9,7,9,3,2,3,8,4)

Comment: for the second part would it be ?                                                                                       B<-matrix(A1,nrow = 5,ncol = 4,byrow = T)

Comment: `read.table` gives you a `data.frame`, so you can access the second column with one of several ways: `A[,2]` (where `A` is the table returned by `read.table`), `A[[2]]`, and (in this case, because of the column names assigned) `A$V2`. All three of those return a vector of the entire column. Since you want a subset, you then should use the `[` again to subset the full 20,000-element vector into just 20 digits. (I doubt highly that the intent of the assignment was to have you assign the literal values `c(3,1,4,1,5,9,2,...)`, my guess is that the teacher/prof wanted you to do it with *code*.)